# Error Funciones fuera de clase con templates

Tags: c++

Estaba haciendo esta clase con `templates` en un archivo header( osea `arreglo.h`), pero el editor me subraya en rojo la palabra `Arreglo` que indica en el código. Y al seleccionar ese subrayado me dice :**name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name**. ¿Cual es el problema?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Arreglo{
        T* arreglo;
        int indice;
        int nElementos;
    public:
        Arreglo(int n){
            this->n = n;
        }

        ~Arreglo(){}

        void agregar(T);
};

template<class T>
void Arreglo::agregar(T arreglo){// <------------------------ subraya la palabra "Arreglo"
    cout<<"A";
}
```

Comment: a tu funcion le falta designar la template prueba asi `void Arreglo<T>::agregar(T arreglo){}` lee aqui para aprender la sintaxis con ejemplos: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Answer (score 1):

Cuando separas la declaración de la definición en una plantilla (`template`), no debes olvidar decirle al compilador qué parte de la definición es la plantilla.

Así pues, cuando la plantilla es el objeto:

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
    void f();
};
```

La definición debe incluir los parámetros plantilla en el objeto:

```
template <typename T>
void S<T>::f(){}
//   ^^^^ <--- Parámetros plantilla en el objeto.
```

Si la plantilla fuese la función miembro:

```
struct S {
    template <typename T>
    void f();
    template <typename T>
    void g(T);
};
```

La definición no necesita incluir los parámetros plantilla en la función<sup>1</sup>, pero si necesitas decir que es una plantilla:

````
template <typename T>
void S::f() {}
template <typename T>
void S::g(T) {}```
//        ^ <--- Parámetro plantilla de la función.
````

Si tanto el objeto como la función miembro son plantillas...

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    template <typename U>
    void f();
    template <typename V>
    void g(V);
};
```

... debes facilitar dos grupos de parámetros plantilla:

```
template <typename T> // Plantilla del objeto
template <typename U> // Plantilla de la función miembro
void S<T>::f() {}
//   ^^^^ <--- Parámetros plantilla en el objeto.

template <typename T> // Plantilla del objeto
template <typename U> // Plantilla de la función miembro
//           v <--- Parámetro plantilla de la función
void S<T>::g(U) {}
//   ^^^^ <--- Parámetro plantilla en el objeto.
```

Observa que en la definición y la declaración hemos usado nombres diferentes para el parámetro plantilla de la función miembro `g`, esto es válido (aunque sea confuso) mientras la definición coincida con la declaración.

Aclarado todo esto, veamos tu caso:

1. Te falta la plantilla en el lado del objeto.

   ```
   template<class T>
   void Arreglo<T>::agregar(T arreglo){
       cout<<"A";
   }
   ```
2. Tu objeto no dispone de objeto `n`, te fallará al construirlo:

   ```
   Arreglo(int n){
       this->n = n;
   //  ~~~~~~~ <--- Esto no existe.
   }
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>A no ser que quieras hacer una especialización de plantilla, pero eso da para otra pregunta.